# Wrap escaped tags

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, html-escape-characters

I would like to wrap escaped tags in divs, so as to be able to manipulate escaped text (each part  separately properly to tags) e.g.

`<div><p> </p></div>`

after escape

`&lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`

I want to change it to

`<div class="wrapper-div">&lt;div&gt;`
`<div class="wrapper-p">&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</div>`
`&lt;/div&gt;</div>`

I can include code in a site, wrap by jquery all tags, then make big RegExp to escape it manually, but is an easier way that does it without using DOM and more automatic?

Or Is any function which can change string like `"<div><p... ..>"` into jquery objects tree (without append it to DOM) so I could easier manipulate this by jquery.

Comment: couldn't this be achieved by a simple find+replace? `<div>` -> `<div class="wrapper-div">&lt;div&gt;`, etc. and `</(anything)>` -> `</div>` or is the input likely to be more complicated?

Comment: Are you looking for `$('<div><p> </p></div>')`?

Comment: Thank you, I think that replacing will be fine in my project.

I was looking for somethink like $('<div .... v>') at first but this is the longer way.

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML5 contenteditable.

See http://jsfiddle.net/utg9N/1/

```
<div class="wrapper-div" contenteditable=true
>&lt;div&gt; <div class="wrapper-p">&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</div> &lt;/div&gt;</div>
```